# Cannot import classes and functions from rest_framework (Django)

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am seeking assistance in setting up and using **rest_framework** in **Django**. I am trying to create views for a REST API in Django but my code editor is unable to import `api_view`  and `Response` from the `rest_framework.decorations` and `rest_framework.response` respectively.  I am just learning Django so I know I have probably done something wrong. I have been able to troubleshoot all the other challenges but this one has given me the runaround for hrs.
In the image I have attached, I have drawn boxes around the `views.py`, rest_framework folder, and the error I am getting. [see the error I am getting in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbEHi.png)
. I have also added `'rest_framework'` in `settings.py`.
I am running Django v5.0.1, Python v3.12, and RESTframework v3.14.0.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am unsure of what to do next. The search results I am getting on the internet around the issue do not address my problem specifically.

Comment: There is no 'decorations' module in the rest framework. It is "from rest_framework.decorators import api_view"